# Searching for parts of strings using Python and Beautiful soup

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am currently using Beautiful Soup to try and find link text on a website and then to pull the links. I am using the following code:

```
source = requests.get('http://www.website').text
page = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
for article in page.find_all('article'):
    for a in article.find_all('a', string=['something']) and article.find_all('a', string=['something']):
        link = a['href']
        print(link)
```

The issue is, Beautiful Soup only finds the links if I have the exact link text, which is not always possible. Is there a way I can search for a link by a portion of its link text?

Comment: What as example?

Comment: hi. if you get bored checkout the tour for some free loot just read through: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

regex example:

```
import re
r = re.compile('something|somethingelse')
for a in article.find_all('a', string=r):
    print(a['href'])
```

from the version you have:

```
from itertools import chain
c = chain(article.find_all('a', string=['something']), 
          article.find_all('a', string=['somethingelse']))
for a in c:
    print(a['href'])
```

function example:

```
def any_string(s):
    ok = ['something', 'somethingelse']
    return (s in ok)

for a in article.find_all('a', string=any_string):
    print(a['href'])
```